# My question relates to KIC 8462852. What are the orbits and suspected objects or planets that have been noted around this star?

Tags: kepler

What are the orbits and suspected objects or planets that have been noted around this star? KIC 8462852

Comment: Is there something puzzling about what you've read in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIC_8462852 http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03622v1 ?

Comment: Orbit: Earth. Object: The telescope itself. Two Earth orbits between the two big episodes of anomalies is at least what I suspect is key to the cause (i.e. a [peryton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peryton#Science)), some kind of telescope or data pipeline anomaly. Similar anomalies have never been confirmed by any other telescope, although such anomalies would be easily observed from Earth.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016, the cause of the fluctuations in not known. There were significant dips in brightness in 2011, and 750 days later in 2013. It was not observed during the next potential dip in 2015. If the dips are caused by an orbiting body or bodies, the next dip will be in May 2017.

Comment: There is apparently a dip being observed now.